# C# Office getting the object where I-Cursor is

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ms-word

I'm looking for a solution where I can get the object where the I-cursor is at the moment of firing a method (the method is run with a button from the ribbon in Word 2010).

Case:
There is a RichTextContentControl Element, when I press with the mouse in it the I-Cursor stays in the text. Then, after pressing the method button from the ribbon, it should take that certain RichTextContentControl Element where the I-cursor was and do some actions:

```
internal void addLock(Object sender)    //object as RichTextContentControl where I-cursor was!
    {
        sender.LockContents = true;
        sender.LockContentControl = true;
    }
```

So far I tried with that above and did some reasearch, but that only gives me the button type from the ribbon that I pressed with the mouse, **not where the I-Cursor was (typing cursor)**.

I hope someone had similar problems and some hints for that.

Edit:

I am generating RichTextContenControlElement with the following code:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private RichTextContentControl richTextControl = null;
    private int index = 0;


    internal void SetRichTextControlOnDocument()
    {

        Document vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);
        index++;

        string name = "MyRichTextBoxControl_"+System.Convert.ToString(index);
        Word.Selection wordSelection = this.Application.Selection;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wordSelection.Text.ToString()))
        {
            Word.Selection selection = this.Application.Selection;
            if (selection != null && selection.Range != null)
            {

                this.richTextControl = vstoDocument.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl(selection.Range, name);
                this.richTextControl.LockContentControl = true;
                this.richTextControl.LockContents = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No text was selceted to lock!", "Error");
        }
    }
```

How can I address the RichText Element that I clicked on respectively where the I cursor is, with "this." ?

Comment: Is this a VSTO solution? Have you tried this.Application.Selection? (this.Application should return the Word application in which the VSTO solution is running)

Comment: Yes I have tried that and I get back: system.__comobject and not that certain richtextcontrolelement.

Comment: At runtime, all the Word objects you're interacting with will be reported as `system.__comobject`. If you hover over `this.Application.Selection` you should see an option for **Dynamic view** which might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped to get an insight of the object. I got a step further and now I can get with `selection.ParentContentControl.Tag.ToString()` the tag of that certain RichTextControl element. But I can't find a way to re-asign it to my `.this` object. `.SelectContentControlsByTag(String tag)` does not work for RichTextContentControls...

Answer (score 0):

Got a working solution to get the Object (e.g. RichTextContentControl element) where the I-Cursor was with the following code. Basically getting the .Tag from the ContentControl and looping through all the ContentControls in the document and picking out the one with the matching tag:

```
        internal void remLock()
    {
        vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);

        Word.Selection selection = this.Application.Selection;

        String s; = selection.ParentContentControl.Tag.ToString();

        remByTag(s);

    }

    private void remByTag(String ccTag)
    {

        if (vstoDocument.ContentControls.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (Word.ContentControl cc in vstoDocument.ContentControls)
            {
                if (cc.Type == Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText)
                {
                    if (cc.Tag.ToString() == ccTag)
                    {
                        cc.LockContentControl = false;
                        cc.LockContents = false;

                        MessageBox.Show("Lock has been removed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Following worked aswell. If you click on a RichTextContentControl element the event asigns it to the local RichTextContentControl:

```
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl rt = null;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Application.ActiveDocument.ContentControlOnEnter += ActiveDocument_ContentControlOnEnter;

    }



    private void ActiveDocument_ContentControlOnEnter(Word.ContentControl cc)
    {
        cc.Type = Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText;

        this.rt = cc;


    }
```